# Construct build error for MakeShared in AWS S3 SDK

Tags: c++, xcode, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, clang++

AWS SDK CPP constructor error when trying to connect/auth with S3 (Xcode)

I am getting error an on the MakeShared constructor. The AWS documentation isn’t really shining a light as to why.

Showing Recent Messages

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX13.3.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/__memory/allocator_traits.h:298:9: No matching function for call to 'construct_at'
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX13.3.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/__memory/shared_ptr.h:292:37: In instantiation of function template specialization 'std::allocator_traits<std::allocator<Aws::S3::S3Client>>::construct<Aws::S3::S3Client, std::shared_ptr<SimplifiedAWSCredentialsProvider> &, Aws::Client::ClientConfiguration &, void, void>' requested here
```

```
PTUploader::PTUploader(const std::string& access_key, const std::string& secret_key, const std::string& region)
    : access_key_(access_key),
      secret_key_(secret_key),
      region_(region)
{
    // Initialize the SDK
    options_.loggingOptions.logLevel = Aws::Utils::Logging::LogLevel::Debug;
    Aws::Utils::Logging::InitializeAWSLogging(
        Aws::MakeShared<Aws::Utils::Logging::DefaultLogSystem>(
            "RunUnitTests", Aws::Utils::Logging::LogLevel::Debug, "aws_sdk_"));
    Aws::InitAPI(options_);

    Aws::Client::ClientConfiguration config;
    config.region = region_;

    // Create credentials
    auto credentialsProvider = std::make_shared<SimplifiedAWSCredentialsProvider>(access_key_, secret_key_);

    // Create S3 client with credentials and config
    s3_client_ = std::make_shared<Aws::S3::S3Client>(credentialsProvider, config);
}
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

Fixed, SDK not compat with C++20, switched compiler to GNU++17